# How to live stream from android device camera to store video chunks on Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm working on a project for an Android solution around video recording and analysis. The idea is that since the video would be huge in size, so I have to design a solution wherein say every 30 minutes (can vary from 1 minute to 30 minutes), my code should pick up a curtailed video file and upload in on the cloud, delete that part from the device, while the camera continues to monitor and capture the video feed.
For eg, once I start streaming or recording at 8:00 AM and use interval of 1 minute,
The video files stored on S3 bucket should have data like:

1st video file - from 8:00 AM to 8:01 AM

2nd video file - from 8:01 AM to 8:02 AM

....

and so on until the stream stops.

For now, I'm using the AmazonKinesisVideoDemoApp from https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples.

I'm using Kinesis Video Streams as a medium where I can start streaming from my android device to kinesis and use GET_HLS_STREAMING_SESSION_URL API in python to get video from stream and store on s3 bucket.

```
def save_chunks_to_s3(init_time, time_range):

    timestamp = datetime.strptime(init_time, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

    while True:

        playback_url = kvam.get_hls_streaming_session_url(StreamName=STREAM_NAME, PlaybackMode='ON_DEMAND', 
            HLSFragmentSelector={
            'FragmentSelectorType': 'SERVER_TIMESTAMP',
            'TimestampRange': {
                'StartTimestamp': timestamp,
                'EndTimestamp': timestamp + timedelta(seconds=time_range)
                }
            }
        )['HLSStreamingSessionURL']

        vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(playback_url)

        fwidth = int(vcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)) 
        fheight = int(vcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

        length = int(vcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

        current_time = timestamp.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        filename = 'output_'+current_time+'.avi'

        print("Saving to file "+filename)

        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename,fourcc, 20.0, (fwidth,fheight))

        (grabbed, frame) = vcap.read()

        if grabbed:
            # Capturing all the frames
            while(length>0):
                if frame is not None:
                    out.write(frame)
                length -= 1
                (grabbed, frame) = vcap.read()

            out.release()
            vcap.release()

            # Storing to s3 bucket
            with open(filename, 'rb') as data:
                s3.upload_fileobj(data, 'android-kinesis-video-chunks', 'android_stream_'+filename)


            print("Saved to file "+filename)

            timestamp = timestamp + timedelta(seconds=time_range)

        else:
            out.release()
            vcap.release()
            break



s3 = boto3.client("s3")

kvs = boto3.client("kinesisvideo")

response = kvs.get_data_endpoint(APIName="GET_HLS_STREAMING_SESSION_URL", StreamName=STREAM_NAME)

# Grab the endpoint from GetDataEndpoint
endpoint = response['DataEndpoint']

# Grab the HLS Stream URL from the endpoint
kvam = boto3.client("kinesis-video-archived-media", 
        endpoint_url=endpoint, 
        region_name=REGION_NAME, 
        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

while True:
    try:
        # This will throw ResourceNotFoundException if not streaming
        live_url = kvam.get_hls_streaming_session_url(StreamName=STREAM_NAME, PlaybackMode="LIVE")['HLSStreamingSessionURL']
        init_utc_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

        start_time = time.time()

        # Storing will start after a delay of 90s after live stream started
        while(time.time()-start_time<90):
            print(time.time()-start_time)

        # Using interval range of 1 minute
        save_chunks_to_s3(init_utc_time, 60)


    except:
        print("Waiting for live stream......")
```

I'm running the above code on my local machine before starting the video stream on android device.
But the requirement is to either run this using some serverless solution or find some other solution where video is directly streamed to S3.